# Multiple Kronecker Products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, quantum-mechanics, kronecker-product

Looking at this paper here (see page 5, just above equation (7)) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.09225v1.pdf...

It shows an equation:

$$
X_{3of4} = I \otimes I \otimes X \otimes I
$$
Where $I$ is a 2x2 identity matrix, and X is the matrix:
$$
 X = \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{matrix} \right]
$$

How would you work this out, as once you did $I \otimes I$, you would have a 4x4 matrix, so you couldn't then do it to the $X$ matrix...

Any help would be appreciatied

Comment: I don't understand what your confusion here is. Certainly, you can compute $$ ((I\otimes I)\otimes X)\otimes I $$ Or, if there's an issue there, what is it? Nothing about the Kronecker product necessitates that the two matrices have the same shape or size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just for fun,
\begin{align}
I \otimes I \otimes X \otimes I
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
.
\end{align}

As @Omnomnomnom points out, having computed one of the [Kronecker products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), you can continue with the others.

You can do this e.g. in Matlab/Octave with

`I = eye(2); X = [0 1; 1 0]; kron(kron(kron(I, I), X), I)`.

Comment: Thanks for that ;) did you just do them sequentially? The comment above said you don't actually need them to be the same size, that true?

Comment: Ah yes! Thanks for that!

Comment: @ user66081 , your equality $I\otimes I\otimes X\otimes I=\cdots$ is not quite correct. More precisely, $(E\otimes F)\otimes G$ and $E\otimes(F\otimes G)$ are not the same space but are isomorphic under a canonical isomorphism. Then, if you want explicitly write such a multiple tensor product, then you must choose some bracketing. Clearly, the explicit result depends on such a choice.

Comment: @loupblanc: I understand; but we are talking about the Kronecker product of matrices here

Comment: @ user66081 , yes, you are right.